# How to make clients PM messages in our codes in Java?

Tags: java, client-server

What our code does right now is there are clients and one server, and the clients can send their messages through the server. The problem is, we need to do client-client, so the client's message must go directly to the other client's chat box. We can only see what they are talking about in the server chatbox not in the clients' chatboxes. Apparently it can only do client-server. Please help? Thanks!

SampleServer.java

```
        /*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */

        /**
         *
         * @author Kim
         */
        import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.util.*;
        import java.lang.Object.*;


        public class SampleServer{

            private ObjectOutputStream output; //output stream->flows from my computer to the other computer
            private ObjectInputStream input; //input stream->receive stuff
            private ObjectInputStream name; //input stream->receive stuff
            private Socket connection; //socket variable
            private String user;
            private String ip;
            private PrintWriter p;
            private BufferedReader fromC;
            private serverTest server; //Saves the server test to append messages.

            //constructor
            public SampleServer(Socket c, String username, String userip, serverTest t){  //EDITED!!
                connection = c;
                server = t;
                ip= userip;
                user= username;             
                //setupStreams(); //set up output and input stream

                try{
               output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); //computer who we communicate to
               output.flush(); //bytes of information that is send to other person (leftover)
               input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); //receive messages
               showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");
               }catch(IOException ioException){
                   ioException.printStackTrace();

               }

            }

            public void run() //This method gets called when Thread starts running
            {
                whileChatting();
                closeAll();
            }

           //get stream to send and receive data
           private void setupStreams(){
               try{
               output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); //computer who we communicate to
               output.flush(); //bytes of information that is send to other person (leftover)
               input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); //receive messages
               showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");
               }catch(IOException ioException){
                   ioException.printStackTrace();

               }
           }

           //actual chat conversation
           private void whileChatting(){
               String message = "You are now connected!";
               sendMessage(message); 
               do{
                   try{
                       message = (String) input.readObject(); //views it as an object and make sure it's a string
                       showMessage("\n" + message);
                   }catch(Exception e){
                       //showMessage("\nError!");
                   }
               }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));

           }

           //close streams and sockets 
           public void closeAll(){
               showMessage("\n Closing connection... \n");
               try{
                   output.close();
                   input.close();
                   connection.close();
               }catch(IOException ioException){
                   ioException.printStackTrace();

               }
           }

           //send message to other computer
           public void sendMessage(String message){
               try{
                   output.writeObject("SERVER - " +message); //sends the mesage to the output stream
                   output.flush(); //push extra bytes to user
               }catch(IOException ioException){
                   showMessage("\n ERROR!"); //put in the chat area

               }

           }

           //updates chatWindow
           private void showMessage(String text){
               server.showMessage(text);
           }

        }
```

ServerTest.java

```
        /*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */

        /**
         *
         * @author Kim
         */
        import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.util.*;
        import java.lang.Object.*;

        public class serverTest extends JFrame {
            private JTextField userText; //message variable area
            private JTextArea chatWindow; //display the conversation
            private ServerSocket server; //server variable
            private Vector<String> users;
            private Vector<String> ips;
            private JTextArea conList;
            private ArrayList<SampleServer> connections = new ArrayList<SampleServer>();

            public static void main(String[] args){
                new serverTest();
            }

            public serverTest()
            {
                super("Instant Messenger");
                userText = new JTextField(); //text field
                userText.addActionListener(
                        new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
                                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand()); //sends the message
                                userText.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                );
                add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                users = new Vector();
                ips = new Vector();
                chatWindow = new JTextArea();
                conList = new JTextArea();
                conList.setEditable(false);
                add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
                add(new JScrollPane(conList), BorderLayout.EAST);
                conList.append("   ONLINE USERS    \n");
                setSize(300, 150);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setVisible(true);

               try {
                   server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100); //port number and only 100 can connect to the server
                   while(true){
                       try{
                            showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect...\n");
                            Socket connection = server.accept(); //once someone asked for connection, accepts this
                            //showMessage("Now connected to "+connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); //converts the ip address to string

                            ips.add(connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); // adds ip address of client to ips vector

                            BufferedReader fromC = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); // gets what client sent through printwriter - username
                            String s = new String(fromC.readLine()); // saves as string
                            users.add(s); // saves username of client to users vector
                            String con = (connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                            showMessage(s + " / " + con + " has connected.");

                            Iterator c = users.iterator(); // username iterator
                            Iterator b = ips.iterator(); // ip address iterator

                            conList.setText("");

                            while(c.hasNext()) {

                                String d = (c.next()).toString(); // gets next element in users vector
                                String e = (b.next().toString()); // gets next element in ips vector
                                conList.append(d + "\n"); // displays username in online users list
                                conList.append("(" + e + ")\n\n"); // displays ip in online users list
                            }
                            final SampleServer se = new SampleServer(connection, s, con, this);
                            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    se.run();
                                }
                            });
                            t.start();
                            connections.add(se);

                       }catch(EOFException eofException){
                           showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
                       }
                   }

               }catch(IOException ioException){
                   ioException.printStackTrace();
               }
            }

            public void closeAll()
            {
                while (!connections.isEmpty())
                {
                    connections.get(0).closeAll();
                    connections.remove(0);
                }
            }

            public void sendMessage(String text)
            {
                        showMessage("\n SERVER - " + text);
                for (SampleServer s : connections)
                {
                    s.sendMessage(text);
                }
            }

            public void showMessage(final String text)
            {
               SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //updats GUI or threads
                       new Runnable(){
                           public void run(){
                               chatWindow.append(text); //add string at the end of the chatWindow
                           }
                       }
               );
            }
        }
```

clientTest.java

```
        /*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */

        /**
         *
         * @author Kim
         */
            import javax.swing.*;

            public class clientTest {

                public String userName;
                private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Messenger");

                    private static String getUsername() {
                    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        frame,
                        "Enter Username:",
                        "Instant Messenger",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                }

                public static void main(String[] args){

                    String username = getUsername();//getting username
                    SampleClient client;                     
                    client = new SampleClient("localhost", username); //localhost

                    client.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    client.startRunning();
                }

            }
```

sampleClient.java

```
        /*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */

        /**
         *
         * @author Kim
         */
        import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import javax.swing.*;

        public class SampleClient extends JFrame{

        private JTextField userText;
        private JTextArea chatWindow;
        private ObjectOutputStream user;
        private ObjectOutputStream output;
        private ObjectInputStream input; //from the server
        private String message = "";
        private String serverIP;
        private Socket connection;
        private String name;
        private JTextArea contacts;
        private PrintWriter toS;

        //constructor
        public SampleClient(String host, String username){
            super("Client");
            serverIP = host;
            name = username;
            userText = new JTextField();
            userText.setEditable(false); //not allowed to type while no one is connected
            userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                        userText.setText("");

                    }

                }
                );
            add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            contacts = new JTextArea();
            chatWindow = new JTextArea();
            add(new JScrollPane(contacts), BorderLayout.EAST); //scroll
            contacts.append("   ONLINE CONTACTS   \n");
            add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER); //scroll
            setSize(300, 150);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        //connect to server
        public void startRunning(){
            try {

                connectServer();
                setupStreams();
                whileChatting();

            }catch(EOFException eofException){
                showMessage("\n Client terminated connection");
            }catch (IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                closeAll();
            }
        }

        //connectServer
        private void connectServer() throws IOException{
            showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
            connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789); //passes to an IP Adrdress and Port Number
            showMessage("Connected to:" + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); //prompt
            toS = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);
            toS.println(name);

        }

        //set up streams for sending and receive the messages
        private void setupStreams()throws IOException{
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); //receive messages
            showMessage("\n Streams are connected");

        }

        //actual chat
        private void whileChatting()throws IOException{
            ableToType(true);
            do{
                try{
                    message = (String) input.readObject();
                    showMessage("\n" +message);
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                    showMessage("\n ERROR!");
                }
            }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
        }

        //close sockets and streams
        private void closeAll(){
            showMessage("\n Closing connections..");
            ableToType(false);
            try{
                output.close();
                input.close();
                connection.close();
            }catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //send messages to server
        private void sendMessage(String message){
            try{
                output.writeObject( "\n" + name + ": " + message);
                output.flush(); //push bytes
                showMessage("\n" + name + ": " + message);

            }catch(IOException ioException){
                chatWindow.append("ERROR!");

            }
        }

        //Update chatWindow
        private void showMessage(final String m){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            chatWindow.append(m); //appear at the end of the conversation

                        }
                    }
            );

        }

        //permission to type to for user
        private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            userText.setEditable(tof);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
        }
```

Comment: If the problem is only about who can "see" the messages, then I would simply add more meta data to the message in stead of flipping the entire system on its side to achieve a direct peer to peer connection. A 'private' boolean flag might already be enough perhaps, then based on that flag the client application can decide to display it in the server window or in a private window.

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to achieve it with TCP because if you have 10 clients in neighbor then you have to open 10 ports for each client. If you think you can handle it then you should have both `ServerSocket` and `Socket` on your system opened that means listening and writing on streams parallely .

But this can be achieve by UDP but there are many limitations and UDP is not easy.